# Apache2 child process mine.32 high CPU

Tags: apache-2.2

Some processes which Apache2 has forked off has extremely high CPU usage. Specifically `mine.32` What is it and how can I reduce it's CPU usage?

Top:

```
PID     USER      PR  NI   VIRT    RES  SHR  S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
10834   www-data  20   0   99108   1284 1012 S  315  0.1 592:21.41 mine.32
11871   www-data  20   0   99108   1276  996 S  315  0.1 114:06.83 mine.32
 8540   www-data  20   0   69816    29m 6976 S    0  2.9   3:49.47 apache2
10069   www-data  20   0   79188    36m 7388 S    0  3.7  41:04.19 apache2
10071   www-data  20   0   74296    31m 7340 S    0  3.2  40:06.74 apache2
10078   www-data  20   0   82144    39m 7500 S    0  4.0  43:36.85 apache2
10079   www-data  20   0   74324    31m 7376 S    0  3.2  37:04.56 apache2
10099   www-data  20   0   74588    31m 7152 S    0  3.2  42:22.07 apache2
10100   www-data  20   0   82024    39m 7384 S    0  3.9  41:21.16 apache2
```

**EDIT**

Follow up question: [Prevent from shell script executing by Apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/504324/prevent-from-shell-script-executing-by-apache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mine.32 executable part of the Apache package.

Most likely origins:

- The process was launched as a CGI by apache (check apache logs or mine.32's PPID, is it an apache process)
- It was started by another means (eg crontab) to run as user www-data (PPID?)
- The www-data account was compromised (through an insecure site you're hosting) and Arty Bartfast is riding your CPU

Comment: Yes it was compromised. Found it in a wordpress JS directory

Comment: Could you assist with http://serverfault.com/questions/504324/prevent-from-shell-script-executing-by-apache

Answer (score 2):

you can check full running command instead only command name with top as below

> top -c

and also you can check it from process id as below:

```
cat /proc/<PID>/cmdline
```

e.g.

```
cat /etc/10834/cmdline
```

here you can see what is running in this process or check as below:

> ps -aufx |grep mine.32